# Como trazer dado de uma coluna dataframe para outro

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tenho um dataframe onde tenho informações como id, name, company e preciso juntar ele em outro dataframe que só tenho o ownerId.
Ex:

```
users= pd.DataFrame([['Jay',16,'BBA'],
                   ['Jack',19,'BTech'],
                   ['Mark',18,'BSc']],
                  columns = ['name','id','company'])

historico = pd.DataFrame([['12-03-2022',16],
                   ['11-05-2022',19],
                   ['03-01-2021',18]],
                  columns = ['data','ownerId'])
```

Preciso colocar os dados do `user.name` no lugar do `historico.ownerId`

Pensei em algo como:

```
historico.ownerId = (historico.ownerId == users['id'], user['name'])
```

Mas não funcionou, como poderia fazer isso?

Comment: mas preciso que o user.id seja igual ao historico.ownerId e então pegar o users['name'], isso que não estou conseguindo

Comment: A pergunta continua ambígua. Você quer que seja feito o relacionamento entre dois dataframes usando como chave as colunas `users['id']` e `historico['ownerId']` porém não especificou se os valores encontrados nessas colunas serão únicos ou podem ocorrer duplicatas, não especificou se se haverão linhas vazias ou NA e não especificou se ocorrem e o que fazer com valores não relacionáveis. Numa situação perfeita onde não tenha que gerenciar adversidades teste `print(users.join(historico.set_index('ownerId'), on='id'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá para realizar isso você poderia utilizar o **merge** para juntar as duas tabelas e após isso deixar somente as colunas desejadas.

Segue abaixo como ficaria o código

```
historico = pd.merge(
    left = users[['name','id']],
    right = historico,
    left_on = 'id',
    right_on = 'ownerId',
    how = 'inner'
)
```

Desta forma você obterá o seguinte resultado
[**Imagem após o merge.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkr3H.png) 
Agora basta remover as colunas com um **drop** 
`historico.drop(columns=['ownerId','id'],inplace=True)`, que ai você tera exatamente o DataFrame da maneira que deseja [**DataFrame desejado**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jILJK.png).

> Caso o conceito de merge sejá novo para você sugiro dar uma olhada na **[Documentação](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)**, ou neste artigo **[Pandas: combinando data frames com merge e concat](https://medium.com/data-hackers/pandas-combinando-data-frames-com-merge-e-concat-10e7d07ca5ec)**